How does the BlockCypher API determine whether a transaction is deposited or transferred out
How does the BlockCypher API determine whether a transaction is deposited or transferred out? what's the mean of fields tx_input_n and tx_output_n? i need help, thank u very much!
i can't find out of this, it's so confused
